# Open a new web page on button click in C#, Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, buttonclick

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 and coding in C#.

I wish to open a new webpage, RegistrationForm.aspx (a webpage included within application) on a button click. I have searched a lot on the Internet but nothing useful turned up.

This is my button.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="NavigateToSite" >Search</button>
```

The NavigateToSite function in the code-behind file is defined as follows:

```
protected void NavigateToSite(){
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("~/RegistrationForm");
    }
```

I also tried this

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="window.show('~/RegistrationForm')" >Search</button>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you were really close with doing this in the asp form. Here's a snippet of code from a web application I'm working on that open another page when the button is clicked.

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('History.aspx', '_blank', 'status=no,width=500,height=500'); return false;">View History</a>
```

Comment: That worked well, thank you!
But what if I wish to open the web page in the same tab?

Comment: Instead of "window.ope()" use: <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="imgLink" ImageUrl="image.gif" PostBackUrl="Home.aspx" /> Most important in this clip is the PostBackUrl tag.

Answer (score 0):

`Process.Start` is for starting applications.

`onclick` takes a javascript handler which you are close but you can't use `~`.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to open a page in the same window/tab then you should be using an anchor instead of a button.
You can style the anchor to look like a button using CSS if you wish to do so.

An example for this would be.
    `<a href="RegistrationForm.aspx">Search</a>`

If you're using MVC you can use the [@Html.ActionLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) helper to create links to other areas of your site. If you're using web forms you can use the [HyperLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control to perform this task.

Web Forms example:
    `<asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="~/RegistrationForm.aspx" runat="server" />`

MVC example:
        `@Html.ActionLink("Search", "RegistrationForm")`